# Which gene I should select from this qqplot

Tags: variant-calling, mutations, wgs

I have a qqplot of my whole genome sequencing data; A plot is for showing possibly significant driver genes. I tried to read about qqplot though but people only say about the skewedness while I want to know from these two genes which one are more likely to be driver

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Given that TP53 is the most significant and is already known to have driver mutations in cancer it would seem to be the logical choice.

Comment: Thank you, does that mean I must ignore MAP1S as a candidate even though it has significant p-value but non-significant q-value?

Comment: Nothing I wrote suggests that you *must* ignore MAP1S, your question indicated you only wanted a single candidate. If you're fine with more then take more.

Answer (score 2):

You can't know which is the driver and which is the carrier. At most you can say that a specific gene deviate more of the expected underlying hypothesis. See also [other](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101290/105234) [resources](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/advanced_graphs/q-q_plots.html) [online](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/63104/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_univariate_sect040.htm).

You also seem to ignore other genes that deviate more of your null hypothesis. I recommend to plot the histogram of the p-values to see if the distribution is uniform

Comment: I think it's pretty clear from the QQ-plot that these p-values are uniformly distributed (except for the twenty or so in the tail of the distribution)?

Comment: @winni2k Usually the QQ-plot is centered around 0 (if using `qqnorm`), in this plot it is not centred, also a expected and observed pvalue above 1 indicates that this is not a normal QQ-plot. That's why I recommended the histogram.

Comment: Ah! I see. I think the x and y-axes must be -log10(p-value) as shown for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92124/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot-of-p-values), and not quantiles as would be reported by qqnorm. #missingaxislabels

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a pretty good Q-Q plot. My recollection of doing Q-Q plots is that a good Q-Q requires a "more or less" linear relationship for the model to be considered okay. Again this model looks good, its 1:1, albeit it does deviate a little (for the gene of interest). TP15 falls outside the 1:1.

@Devon Ryan states TP15 has good biological credentials, which is clearly important. It maybe worth checking  MAP15 because this is "more or less" within your model (for my Q-Q plots definitely within the model :-) ).

In summary, its just my opinion - that on the basis of the Q-Q plot the driver is the not the expected candidate.